# How to add empty rows in Laravel blade table

Tags: mysql, laravel, dtr

I'm developing a Daily Time Record (timesheet) and I am trying to achieve this design:

[image: Daily time record]

My database structure is

```
id 
user_id
log_date
log_type (e.g time-in,breakout,break-in,time-out)
log_time
```

I can generate the data but I can't seem to add the rows that have no entries.

Comment: you would at least need a foreign key of users(user_id) and make all the columns except the foreign key and primary key(obviously) nullable. That should do it to add a empty entries for the specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Make all your columns `null` by default through migration or manually in DB except your primary key and foreign key.